# How to extract the primary subject and object phrases from a complex sentence?

Tags: tree, nlp, stanford-nlp

In the documentation for the Stanford Parser, the following example sentence is given:

> The strongest rain ever recorded in India shut down the financial hub
>   of Mumbai, snapped communication lines, closed airports and forced
>   thousands of people to sleep in their offices or walk home during the
>   night, officials said today.

This produces the parse tree:

> [ROOT [S [S [NP [NP [DT The] [JJS strongest] [NN rain] ] [VP [ADVP [RB
>   ever] ] [VBN recorded][PP [IN in] [NP [NNP India] ] ] ] ] [VP [VP [VBD
>   shut] [PRT [RP down] ] [NP [NP [DT the] [JJ financial] [NN hub] ] [PP
>   [IN of] [NP [NNP Mumbai] ] ] ] ] [, ,] [VP [VBD snapped] [NP [NN
>   communication] [NNS lines] ] ] [, ,] [VP [VBD closed] [NP [NNS
>   airports] ] ] [CC and] [VP [VBD forced] [NP [NP [NNS thousands] ] [PP
>   [IN of] [NP [NNS people] ] ] ] [S [VP [TO to] [VP [VP [VB sleep] [PP
>   [IN in] [NP [PRP$ their] [NNS offices] ] ] ] [CC or] [VP [VB walk] [NP
>   [NN home] ] [PP [IN during] [NP [DT the] [NN night] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
>   [, ,] [NP [NNS officials] ] [VP [VBD said] [NP-TMP [NN today] ] ] [.
>   .] ] ]

(see https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjnJT.png).

**What sort of NLP tool would be able to output the sentential subject and object from the above complex sentence example?** Desired output:

```
sentence_subj_phrase = "the strongest rain ever recorded in India"
sentence_obj_phrase = "the financial hub of Mumbai"
```

**FROM ORIGINAL OP's POST** (It's just details about what he's thinks doesn't work):

A naive way of extracting the subject and object in a sentence is to find the noun phrases immediately preceding and succeeding the verb. In complex sentences, however, there are multiple verbs, and thus multiple subjects and objects. It is possible to consider complex sentences like this as multiple sentences (using the first part of the independent clause as the "root", and replacing the second part with each of the dependent clauses), but usually the first clause is the most important and could be considered the main "topic" of the sentence.

Doing a simple BFS to find the first NP prior to a verb will result in "officials" being the subject, since it is at the lowest depth level. This doesn't capture the intuition of the first clause containing the subject. One approach I tried was searching for the NPs in the first "base" S node (i.e., lowest level subtree rooted at an S node), but in this case that would capture nodes rooted at S<sub>3</sub>.

Comment: What is this!!!
Is this a question, or the confused answer to the question itself???

Comment: people will be tired getting your question properly.

Comment: It is an actual question (as you can see in the last paragraph), but I felt I needed to explain a fair amount about what I'm trying to do before it could be understood. If it helps clarity, I can put the question itself closer to the beginning.

Comment: Fair enough, but I don't see why this warrants voting down the question since it hasn't been asked before in this form, and could also potentially be useful to others doing this type of information extraction.

Comment: I was not behind downvoting your question. Don't blame without knowing proprly.

Comment: But "officials" *is* the main subject in this sentence. You can read it as "(Today) **officials** say that ..." and the entire remaining of the sentence is a subclause. This subclause has its own subject, "the strongest **rain** ever recorded in India".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some points to take note, when you talk about grammatical subjects and objects, they are following [structuralist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_linguistics) theory of linguistics, which most NLP tasks adhere to.

Next when you talk about grammatical subjects and object, you should only refer to the entity (i.e. the thing/event) itself and that excludes the entity modifiers:
"the strongest rain ever recorded in India"

```
entity = "rain"
entity modifiers = [('Adjective/Preposition_Phrase', "ever recorded in India"), ("Determiners", "the"), (Adjective_Phrase, "strongest")]
entity phrase = "The strongest rain"
entity phrase with all posssible modifiers (EP_mod)= "the strongest rain ever recorded in India"
```

Then we come down to the NLP task of how to detect `EP_mod`:

1. First, you can try to **figure out an algorithm that determines the primary predicate** (i.e. verb in shallow computational grammar) in the complex sentence. (I suggest, find the verb in the top most hierarchy of the parse tree)
2. Then, you need to **find the phrase that contains the SUBJ/OBJ entity** of the primary predicate. (Any normal NLP parser should tell you this)
3. Lastly, you need to **find the modifiers of the phrase** that contains the SUBJ/OBJ entity of the primary predicate (Possibly you need to find a dependency parser (Stanford parser is a dependency parser) that gives you the annotation that says `SUBJ_phrase governs Modifier_phrase`)

What you're asking for is a mish-mash of current existing tools, so the best solution is the [eat your own dog food](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eating_your_own_dog_food) solution. Have fun with it =)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I know that the NP can be further broken down into the specific noun and its modifiers, but this is made trivial by the parser and isn't that important to me for my application. Why do you suggest the topmost verb subtree?

Comment: because in dependency parsing, the top most verb in the hierarchy is usually the governing predicate of the sentence. so in sentences like `i think he is good`, `think` would be the main predicate of the sentence. `the hotel was bombed because the terrorist doesn't like capitalism`. You should take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Government_and_binding_theory

Comment: Intuitively that definitely sounds reasonable, but again, for my example sentence that will focus on "officials said today", which is basically parenthetical and not the most important thing about the sentence. Perhaps I really should just be breaking up complex sentences into simple ones, at which point using the topmost VP would be sensible.

Comment: you need an algorithm, some criterion that makes you choose the `primary predicate`. Then evaluate the algorithm to see how much it's far from 100%, then look at the instances and see whether you can fix the bug and once you reach >90% to select the primary predicate, you can stop tweaking the algorithm

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be mixing up the notions of topic and grammatical subject to some extent.  "officials" is a perfectly good grmmatical subject of "said".  As you sort of explain, you should think about finding subjects of clauses ("S" subtrees in the tree) rather than subjects of sentences.  "the strongest rain..." is the grammatical subject of S_2 in your example.

If all you want is the first grammatical subject in any clause in the sentence, find all subjects in all S subtrees using whatever algorithm you've chosen (the NP in an S->NP VP subtree, etc.) and then pick the one that's furthest to the left in the whole tree.  (This obviously won't necessarily find a phrase that's a good topic, though.)

Comment: I do realize that there are multiple grammatical subjects and objects in this sentence (as I said), but I'm trying to determine the best way to select *one* of each (which, yes, loses some information). Do you have any justification for picking the leftmost subtree as opposed to the topmost (i.e., the least "nested")? Or is it so dependent on the specific sentence that you are just suggesting this arbitrarily?

Comment: It wasn't arbitrary, it was because you said you wanted to find the first one: "This doesn't capture the intuition of the first clause containing the subject."  None of your proposed algorithms found the subject of the left-most finite verb in the sentence, which was the one you claimed to be looking for.  For reliably finding some kind of topic it's obviously not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Python Spacy method:

### Code

```
from spacy.en import English
nlp = English()


SUBJECTS = ["nsubj","nsubjpass"] ## add or delete more as you wish
OBJECTS = ["dobj", "pobj", "dobj"] ## add or delete more as you wish


sent = "The strongest rain ever recorded in India shut down the financial hub of Mumbai, snapped communication lines, closed airports and forced thousands of people to sleep in their offices or walk home during the night, officials said today."

doc=nlp(sent)
sub_toks = [tok for tok in doc if (tok.dep_ in SUBJECTS) ]
obj_toks = [tok for tok in doc if (tok.dep_ in OBJECTS) ]

print("Subjects:", sub_toks)
print("Objects :", obj_toks)
```

### Result

```
Subjects: [rain, officials]
Objects : [India, hub, Mumbai, lines, thousands, people, offices, night]
```